# Which years did US Senate had filibuster-proof majorities?

Tags: united-states, senate

Which of the years did the US Senate held a filibuster-proof majority for one party - e.g. 60 seats? (or 3/5th of total - e.g. the number was lower when # of Senators was lower)

This includes "affiliated" nominally independent senators, e.g. Bernie Sanders may not count towards DNC majority technically speaking, but is a part of it practically speaking.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in time periods when filibuster was used, so 1837+? Or even more so, since 1917 when cloture rules were established.

Comment: I found this: http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0774721.html

Comment: Here's another link going back to the beginning of the Senate: http://www.senate.gov/pagelayout/history/one_item_and_teasers/partydiv.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the Senates website on [Party Division](http://www.senate.gov/history/partydiv.htm), and a night of boredom, the following table reflects the Senate periods and their number that the majority party enjoyed a super majority. Years prior to 1837 not included.

```
    Senate  Start   Fin
    25th    1837    1839
    30th    1847    1849
    33th    1853    1855
    34th    1855    1857
    35th    1857    1859
    37th    1861    1863
    38th    1863    1865
    39th    1865    1867
    40th    1867    1869
    41th    1869    1871
    42th    1871    1873
    43th    1873    1875
    44th    1875    1877
    57th    1901    1903
    58th    1903    1905
    59th    1905    1907
    60th    1907    1909
    61th    1909    1911
    67th    1921    1923
    73th    1933    1935
    74th    1935    1937
    75th    1937    1939
    76th    1939    1941
    77th    1941    1943
    86th    1959    1961
    87th    1961    1963
    88th    1963    1965
    89th    1965    1967
    90th    1967    1969
    94th    1975    1977
    95th    1977    1979
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it's probably worth adding the most recent example: the 111th Congress from June 30, 2009 (when Al Franken was sworn in) to February 4, 2010 (when Scott Brown was sworn in.)

Comment: @reirab - June 30 to August 25, then September 25 to February 4, to account for the time Kennedy's seat was vacant due to his demise.  Hair-splitting, I know.  Also, how much of that time before his death was he unable to vote or participate?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Good point, though [it doesn't appear any closure votes failed from June 19 through Oct 8](https://www.senate.gov/pagelayout/reference/cloture_motions/111.htm#result_key). During the Aug 25 - Sept 25 period, closure was apparently only filed 4 times and withdrawn each time with no actual roll calls.